# ZMQ and Twisted

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, zeromq

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple, but I'm not sure how to go about it...

I have an application that publishes messages over a ZMQ PUB socket. I'd like to write a small server that subscribes to these updates and broadcasts them to all connected websocket clients.

This seems simple on the surface, but I don't know how to trigger an event in the twisted reactor when data is received through the subscription. I know ZMQ has an ioloop as well, but it is not the same as twisted...

What's the best way to go about this? I don't have to use twisted, some other python framework will do if something can deal with this better (rpclib?)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use ØMQ with Twisted, you can use [txZMQ](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/txZMQ/).  The documentation on the linked page has a couple of basic examples which ought to get you started.